# Accessing Raspberry Pi from Web

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, web-hosting, raspbian, dyndns

I recently got myself a Raspberry Pi 2 where I installed Apache 2 to create a web server hosted from home.

I activated Dynamic DNS for mydomain.com which successfully points to the public IP of my Raspberry Pi located in my home network which is also running ddclient.

My Router is a FritzBox 7360 where I activated port forwarding for the ports 22 (SSH), 80 (HTTP) and 5901 (VNC) which are all pointing to the Raspberry Pi. I also added my domain as an exception to the DNS-Rebinding-Protection in my router.

[image: Port forwarding]

I have no problem accessing the Raspberry Pi from my home network. I can SSH into it and I get the standard Apache 2 placeholder site shown over the browser.

[image]

The problems begin when I try to access the Raspberry Pi from the web. I always get "Operation timed out". When I ping the domain I always get a 100% package loss.

I really don't know where to look for the problem anymore. So any input or actually solving my problem will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: looks like your ddns isn't correctly configured. check whether your ddns for "mydomain.com" really points to the public IP address of your router [check-ip-address](http://whatismyipaddress.com/)

Comment: @TomMekken They point exactly to the same IP address.

Comment: but the ping still dies? if you `ping mydomain.com` then you just ping your router through the internet. when the ping doesn't work, then either you have ICMP turned off on your fritzbox your fritzbox hasn't notified its correct IP to the ddns.

Comment: @TomMekken It actually turned out I was using a DS-Lite connection so I had to update my settings from IPv4 to IPv6. Then everything worked. Thanks!